# Forcing iframe to autoplay through simple JS

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I have a sample video that is the result of a user dragging videos from youtube into a page block for a lightweight CMS. The video shows fine on the interface result, but there is no autoplay even though autoplay is chosen from the YouTube API.

Is there a way, possibly through JS, that I can just set any iframe on the page to autoplay in the event that the youtube API option doesn't work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/id?start=1" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0"; autoplay; allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can autoplay videos from YT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'p2FZvPLWf_M',
          playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1 },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          //setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work though because the user is just dragging youtube videos into the page, so this is too customized I believe. Is there not a way to just force the iframe to play?

Comment: I guess I'm just wondering if the step 3 of the code is necessary since there will be an iframe already on page creation